# opencyc 2.0 error while starting the server

Tags: java, jvm

I have recently downloaded opencyc 2.0 . I tried to start the server via ./run-cyc.sh , but i am getting the following error

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Unrecognized VM option 'UseSpinning'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Cyc server has shut down at Sun Nov 11 19:36:50 IST 2012
```

Anyone knows how this error came?

Comment: I was going to try to answer this, but Opencyc 2.0 only seems to be available as a 300+Mb download.  And even then it is unclear that the bundle includes the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd double check which one of the million different versions of Java you're using. OpenCyc 2.0 was released in 2009, so I'm guessing it's incompatible with the more recent version you have installed.

Is there any reason you didn't try OpenCyc 4.0, which was just released [last month](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencyc/files/OpenCyc%204.0/)? I haven't tried it, but in general you'll have fewer problems with the most recent code.